# How to validate array combinations of Object Property values in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is My JSFiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/nhupL4gs/
This is my code.

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.data=[];
  
  $scope.data=[{"label":"name","type":"string"},
         {"label":"email","type":"string"}];
  $scope.addFields = function () {
    var count=0;
    angular.forEach($scope.data,function(obj){
      if(count==2){
        return true;
      }
      var newObj = {'label':obj.label, 'type':obj.type}
      $scope.data.push(newObj);
      count=count+1;
    });
  };
  
  $scope.save=function(){
   console.log($scope.data);
  };
}
```

```html
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input type="button" value="add" ng-click="addFields()"/>
    <div ng-repeat="eachItem in data">
      <label>{{eachItem.label}}</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="eachItem.value" />
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="eachItem in data">
    Value: {{eachItem.value}}
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="save" ng-click="save()"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above code i have an array contains 2 objects. when i click save button without enter data show error message. Otherwise i click add button two more objects push to same array that is completed . After adding objects to array when i enter data in first object('name') then click save button show error(enter email).So must and should validate first two objects or other added objects data is mandatory.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you want. So that it will be easy to post the answers. What I understood is, You are dynamically adding the form input and you should throw error if the all are empty.

Comment: First i have two input fields like name and email , then user add click adding two more fields like again name and email. Now i enter data in first two fields no error , otherwise i enter data in newly added fields no error , or i enter data in first field name and newly added fields enter data in last field email now raise error.